# VS Code - where to find every available settings.json configuration option?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

Where I can find good documentation for every available settings.json configuration option so I can configure VS code however I like to?

Comment: every extensions has its own settings and there are a Kazillion extensions, so there is no place where they are all documented, if done right they are documented in the README of the extension and shown on the Extension page and in the Marketplace

Comment: read the VSC docs pages and the Release notes

Comment: For all the built-in settings, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings

Comment: Thanks @ Mark and @rioV8 - that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Open Command Palette and type defaultSettings.json. This file contains a clean slate settings. It's read only[,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rU13Qbvu_g8) but you can copy and paste it into your user settings.json

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an official maintained list of everything, but you can find some guides in the [VS Code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

For theme color reference, you can see the list at [Theme Color documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color).

The closest to what you want may be pressing `Ctrl+,` (or by using the gear menu in the bottom left), you can open a GUI that will show all configurable settings and allow you to search them. For some things, it will tell you to edit it in the settings.json instead, though. In which case, you may need to to look at the documentation for usage instructions.

Answer (score 0):

To effortlessly access the default settings in your VSCode editor, simply enable a specific setting within the workbench. Once activated, every time you open your settings.json file, whether manually through the file explorer or via the command palette, you'll encounter a read-only display of all the default settings.

Here's a visual guide to help you:

[image]

[image]